# Not sure how to adapt ancient image switcher code from using name="foo" to id="foo"

Tags: javascript, w3c-validation, name-attribute

About 19 years ago, I needed a script that changes images using the `onmouseover` event. The script used `name="foo"` which, of course, can no longer be supported by the `<img>` tag. I've literally forgotten how the script works and I need some help adapting it to use `id="foo"`.

This is the script that lives in my `<head>`:

```
<script>
function newImage(arg) {
  if (document.images) {
    rslt = new Image();
    rslt.src = arg;
    return rslt;
  }
}

function changeImages() {
  if (document.images && (preloadFlag == true)) {
    for (var i=0; i<changeImages.arguments.length; i+=2) {
      document[changeImages.arguments[i]].src = changeImages.arguments[i+1];
    }
  }
}

var preloadFlag = false;

function preloadImages() {
  if (document.images) {
    archives_over = newImage("/images/index/menu/archives_over.jpg");
    bio_over = newImage("/images/index/menu/bio_over.jpg");
    poetry_over = newImage("/images/index/menu/poetry_over.jpg");
    preloadFlag = true;
  }
}
</script>
```

...and this is the HTML that lives in my `<body>`:

```
<a href='https://www.foo.com/index.php?page=news'
   onmouseover='changeImages("poetry", "/images/index/menu/poetry_over_static.jpg"); return true;'
   onmouseout='changeImages("poetry", "/images/index/menu/poetry_over_static.jpg"); return true;'
   onmousedown='changeImages("poetry", "/images/index/menu/poetry_over_static.jpg"); return true;'
   onmouseup='changeImages("poetry", "/images/index/menu/poetry_over_static.jpg"); return true;'>
  <img name="poetry" src="/images/index/menu/poetry_over_static.jpg">
</a>
```

If I change `<img name="poetry"` to `<img id="poetry"`, the whole thing stops working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your

```
document[changeImages.arguments[i]]
```

when the first argument is `poetry`, accesses `document.poetry`. Use `getElementById` instead, to select an element with a particular id:

```
function changeImages(id, newSrc) {
  document.getElementById(id).src = newSrc;
}
```

You also might consider attaching listeners properly using `addEventListener`, rather than inline handlers:

```
const a = <select your <a> tag here>
const img = document.getElementById('poetry');
const fn = () => {
  img.src = '/images/index/menu/poetry_over_static.jpg';
}
['mouseover', 'mouseout', 'mousedown', 'mouseup'].forEach((eventType) => {
  a.addEventListener(eventType, fn);
});
```

If you're doing this sort of thing for multiple images on the page, then you can make the code even better by dynamically selecting the `<a>`'s `nextElementSibling`, allowing you to avoid IDs entirely:

```
const fn = ({ target }) => {
  const img = target.nextElementSibling;
  img.src = '/images/index/menu/poetry_over_static.jpg';
}
['mouseover', 'mouseout', 'mousedown', 'mouseup'].forEach((eventType) => {
  a.addEventListener(eventType, fn);
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! :)